# How can I animate transition of a view insertion/removal? Insertion animation doesn't work

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I can't make insertion transition to work in SwiftUI.

I have a `Group` which conditionaly displayes one of two views. When I'm trying to animate the transition, **removal transition works but insertion doesn't** - the view just appears right away without any animation.

I'm pasting below my view code. How can I make this work?
*(Xcode 11.3.1)*

```
struct TestView: View {

    @State private var showView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showView.toggle()
                }

            }) {
                Text("Tap")
            }

            Group {
                if showView {
                    Color.red
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                } else {
                    Color.blue
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .cornerRadius(50)
                }
            }
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading),
                                    removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As @Asperi pointed out in the comment, the code is correct but... it will only work when run on real device. Live previews in Xcode are buggy and apparently doesn't handle transitions very well.

**So the answer for this question is simple: test on real device! :)**

Comment: It looks like works fine. Could you attach screen recording to compare?

Comment: Same here. Could you show/explain, what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @Asperi try to update the the `withAnimation` to `withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2))` and you'll see the issue in a Preview

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov, transitions does not work properly In Preview (looks like limitation), so just don't test them there.

Comment: omg, this information helps a lot. Thanks! Add this as the answer to close the Question
.

Comment: @Asperi, you were right. Those transitions does work when run on real device but they are buggy when running in Xcode Preview :-/ Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I think people will get back to this more and more again. I offer @Asperi to post the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ok, it is just observation from the SwiftUI Preview history and until now (can't say what will be in the next version), but - *transitions do not work properly in Preview at all (static or Live* - it looks like limitation, so just don't test them there.

**Test transitions either on standalone Simulator or, what is preferable, on Real Device.**